# Adding minor tick marks to the x axis in ggplot2 (with no labels)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is example code of a plot that does almost exactly what I want. The only thing I want to add is tick marks on the x axis (same size as the major ticks) according to the minor_breaks defined below.

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(1900,1950,2000), y = c(50,75,60))
    
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))
p + geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(1900,2000,by=10),
                     breaks = seq(1900,2000,by=50),
                     limits = c(1900,2000),
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(20,40,60,80),
                     limits = c(0,100)) +
  theme(legend.position="none",
        panel.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(color='black'),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Comment: I've seen this request many times and haven't seen a good answer.   Options I've seen/used are 1: Use minor grid lines. 2: Manually add tick marks.. (Somewhat of a painful approach, but I can envision a future function/package that can do this.)

Comment: Shameless self-promotion: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34533473/2726564)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This would do it in the precise instance:

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks= seq(1900,2000,by=10), 
                  labels = c(1900, rep("",4), 1950, rep("",4), 2000), 
                  limits = c(1900,2000), expand = c(0,0)) +
```

Here's a function that is not bullet-proof but works to insert blank labels when the beginning and ending major labels are aligned with the start and stopping values for the `at` argument:

```
insert_minor <- function(major_labs, n_minor) {labs <- 
                              c( sapply( major_labs, function(x) c(x, rep("", 4) ) ) )
                              labs[1:(length(labs)-n_minor)]}
```

Test:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))
  p + geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks= seq(1900,2000,by=10), 
                     labels = insert_minor( seq(1900, 2000, by=50), 4 ), 
                     limits = c(1900,2000), expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(20,40,60,80), limits = c(0,100)) +
  theme(legend.position="none", panel.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(color='black'), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Comment: Thanks DWin. That will work for what I'm doing. Didn't even think to effectively make them all major tick marks with blank labels.

Comment: I guess what is really needed is a function that will insert blanks into a sequence. Could be a good followup question.

Comment: Re: inserting blanks into a sequence: [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34533472/insert-blanks-into-a-vector-for-e-g-minor-tick-labels-in-r) my go at it with an example application to minor tick labelling

Comment: If you are here, go look at @adamdsmith's solution - it is elegant and easy to incorporate.

Answer (score 9):

Minor axis ticks without labels can now easily be added with the {ggh4x} package. Only minor modifications to the original plot necessary (see comments in code).

```r
library(ggh4x)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
df <- data.frame(x = c(1900, 1950, 2000), y = c(50, 75, 60))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    minor_breaks = seq(1900, 2000, by = 10),
    breaks = seq(1900, 2000, by = 50), limits = c(1900, 2000),
    guide = "axis_minor" # this is added to the original code
  ) +
  theme(ggh4x.axis.ticks.length.minor = rel(1)) # add this to get the same length
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 8):

Very nice functions above.

A solution I find somewhat simpler or easier to wrap my head around is to simply specify you major axis breaks in the increments you want for both major and minor breaks - so if you want major in increments of 10, and minor in increments of 5, you should nevertheless specify your major increments in steps of 5.

Then, in the theme, you are asked to give a color for the axis text. Rather than choosing *one* color, you can give it a *list* of colors - specifying whatever color you want the major axis number to be, and then NA for the minor axis color. This will give you the text on the major mark, but nothing on the 'minor' mark. Likewise, for the grid that goes inside the plot, you can specify a list for the line sizes, so that there is still a difference in thickness for major and minor gridlines within the plot, even though you are specifying the minor gridlines as major grid lines. As an example of what you could put in theme:

```
panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour = c("white"), size = c(0.33, 0.2)),
panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = c("white"), size = c(0.33, 0.2)),
axis.text.y = element_text(colour = c("black", NA), family = "Gill Sans"),
axis.text.x = element_text(colour = c("black", NA), family = "Gill Sans"),
```

I suspect you can change the size of the outer tick mark in the exact same way, though I haven't tried it.

Comment: I found this way quite usefull to avoid creating new functions. However, it displays a warning: Warning message: Vectorized input to `element_text()` is not officially supported. Results may be unexpected or may change in future versions of ggplot2.

Comment: Hi @Paul - yes it gives a warning. The tidyverse team (who make ggplot) give plenty of warning for things that might be removed in the future, but for now it seems to work perfectly well. The warnings aren't to say that something is wrong but only an indication to watch out in case it changes in the future or doesn't do what you expect (e.g., if you use the function as.tibble() instead of as_tibble() it will warn you that as.tibble() is deprecated)

Answer (score 6):

Although the response above is able to add breaks, thse are not actually the minor_breaks, To do so you could use `annotation_ticks` function, which works similarly to  `annotation_logticks`.

Code function is available [here.](https://rdrr.io/github/hrbrmstr/ggalt/src/R/annotation_ticks.r) You may need to load `grid` package

```
annotation_ticks <- function(sides = "b",
                             scale = "identity",
                             scaled = TRUE,
                             short = unit(0.1, "cm"),
                             mid = unit(0.2, "cm"),
                             long = unit(0.3, "cm"),
                             colour = "black",
                             size = 0.5,
                             linetype = 1,
                             alpha = 1,
                             color = NULL,
                             ticks_per_base = NULL,
                             ...) {
  if (!is.null(color)) {
    colour <- color
  }

  # check for invalid side
  if (grepl("[^btlr]", sides)) {
    stop(gsub("[btlr]", "", sides), " is not a valid side: b,t,l,r are valid")
  }

  # split sides to character vector
  sides <- strsplit(sides, "")[[1]]

  if (length(sides) != length(scale)) {
    if (length(scale) == 1) {
      scale <- rep(scale, length(sides))
    } else {
      stop("Number of scales does not match the number of sides")
    }
  }

  base <- sapply(scale, function(x) switch(x, "identity" = 10, "log10" = 10, "log" = exp(1)), USE.NAMES = FALSE)

  if (missing(ticks_per_base)) {
    ticks_per_base <- base - 1
  } else {
    if ((length(sides) != length(ticks_per_base))) {
      if (length(ticks_per_base) == 1) {
        ticks_per_base <- rep(ticks_per_base, length(sides))
      } else {
        stop("Number of ticks_per_base does not match the number of sides")
      }
    }
  }

  delog <- scale %in% "identity"

  layer(
    data = data.frame(x = NA),
    mapping = NULL,
    stat = StatIdentity,
    geom = GeomTicks,
    position = PositionIdentity,
    show.legend = FALSE,
    inherit.aes = FALSE,
    params = list(
      base = base,
      sides = sides,
      scaled = scaled,
      short = short,
      mid = mid,
      long = long,
      colour = colour,
      size = size,
      linetype = linetype,
      alpha = alpha,
      ticks_per_base = ticks_per_base,
      delog = delog,
      ...
    )
  )
}

#' Base ggproto classes for ggplot2
#'
#' If you are creating a new geom, stat, position, or scale in another package,
#' you'll need to extend from ggplot2::Geom, ggplot2::Stat, ggplot2::Position, or ggplot2::Scale.
#'
#' @seealso \code{\link[ggplot2]{ggplot2-ggproto}}
#' @usage NULL
#' @format NULL
#' @rdname ggplot2-ggproto
#' @export
GeomTicks <- ggproto(
  "GeomTicks", Geom,
  extra_params = "",
  handle_na = function(data, params) {
    data
  },

  draw_panel = function(data,
                        panel_scales,
                        coord,
                        base = c(10, 10),
                        sides = c("b", "l"),
                        scaled = TRUE,
                        short = unit(0.1, "cm"),
                        mid = unit(0.2, "cm"),
                        long = unit(0.3, "cm"),
                        ticks_per_base = base - 1,
                        delog = c(x = TRUE, y = TRUE)) {
    ticks <- list()

    # Convert these units to numbers so that they can be put in data frames
    short <- convertUnit(short, "cm", valueOnly = TRUE)
    mid <- convertUnit(mid, "cm", valueOnly = TRUE)
    long <- convertUnit(long, "cm", valueOnly = TRUE)

    for (s in 1:length(sides)) {
      if (grepl("[b|t]", sides[s])) {

        # Get positions of x tick marks
        xticks <- calc_ticks(
          base = base[s],
          minpow = floor(panel_scales$x.range[1]),
          maxpow = ceiling(panel_scales$x.range[2]),
          majorTicks = panel_scales$x.major_source,
          start = 0,
          shortend = short,
          midend = mid,
          longend = long,
          ticks_per_base = ticks_per_base[s],
          delog = delog[s]
        )

        if (scaled) {
          if (!delog[s]) {
            xticks$value <- log(xticks$value, base[s])
          }
        }

        names(xticks)[names(xticks) == "value"] <- "x" # Rename to 'x' for coordinates$transform

        xticks <- coord$transform(xticks, panel_scales)

        # Make the grobs
        if (grepl("b", sides[s])) {
          ticks$x_b <- with(
            data,
            segmentsGrob(
              x0 = unit(xticks$x, "native"),
              x1 = unit(xticks$x, "native"),
              y0 = unit(xticks$start, "cm"),
              y1 = unit(xticks$end, "cm"),
              gp = gpar(
                col = alpha(colour, alpha),
                lty = linetype,
                lwd = size * .pt
              )
            )
          )
        }
        if (grepl("t", sides[s])) {
          ticks$x_t <- with(
            data,
            segmentsGrob(
              x0 = unit(xticks$x, "native"),
              x1 = unit(xticks$x, "native"),
              y0 = unit(1, "npc") - unit(xticks$start, "cm"),
              y1 = unit(1, "npc") - unit(xticks$end, "cm"),
              gp = gpar(
                col = alpha(colour, alpha),
                lty = linetype,
                lwd = size * .pt
              )
            )
          )
        }
      }


      if (grepl("[l|r]", sides[s])) {
        yticks <- calc_ticks(
          base = base[s],
          minpow = floor(panel_scales$y.range[1]),
          maxpow = ceiling(panel_scales$y.range[2]),
          majorTicks = panel_scales$y.major_source,
          start = 0,
          shortend = short,
          midend = mid,
          longend = long,
          ticks_per_base = ticks_per_base[s],
          delog = delog[s]
        )

        if (scaled) {
          if (!delog[s]) {
            yticks$value <- log(yticks$value, base[s])
          }
        }

        names(yticks)[names(yticks) == "value"] <- "y" # Rename to 'y' for coordinates$transform
        yticks <- coord$transform(yticks, panel_scales)

        # Make the grobs
        if (grepl("l", sides[s])) {
          ticks$y_l <- with(
            data,
            segmentsGrob(
              y0 = unit(yticks$y, "native"),
              y1 = unit(yticks$y, "native"),
              x0 = unit(yticks$start, "cm"),
              x1 = unit(yticks$end, "cm"),
              gp = gpar(
                col = alpha(colour, alpha),
                lty = linetype, lwd = size * .pt
              )
            )
          )
        }
        if (grepl("r", sides[s])) {
          ticks$y_r <- with(
            data,
            segmentsGrob(
              y0 = unit(yticks$y, "native"),
              y1 = unit(yticks$y, "native"),
              x0 = unit(1, "npc") - unit(yticks$start, "cm"),
              x1 = unit(1, "npc") - unit(yticks$end, "cm"),
              gp = gpar(
                col = alpha(colour, alpha),
                lty = linetype,
                lwd = size * .pt
              )
            )
          )
        }
      }
    }
    gTree(children = do.call("gList", ticks))
  },
  default_aes = aes(colour = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = 1, alpha = 1)
)


# Calculate the position of log tick marks Returns data frame with: - value: the
# position of the log tick on the data axis, for example 1, 2, ..., 9, 10, 20, ...
# - start: on the other axis, start position of the line (usually 0) - end: on the
# other axis, end position of the line (for example, .1, .2, or .3)
calc_ticks <- function(base = 10,
                       ticks_per_base = base - 1,
                       minpow = 0,
                       maxpow = minpow + 1,
                       majorTicks = 0,
                       start = 0,
                       shortend = 0.1,
                       midend = 0.2,
                       longend = 0.3,
                       delog = FALSE) {

  # Number of blocks of tick marks
  reps <- maxpow - minpow

  # For base 10: 1, 2, 3, ..., 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, ...
  ticknums <- rep(seq(1, base - 1, length.out = ticks_per_base), reps)

  # For base 10: 1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, ... (for example)
  powers <- rep(seq(minpow, maxpow - 1), each = ticks_per_base)

  ticks <- ticknums * base ^ powers

  ticks <- c(ticks, base ^ maxpow) # Add the last tick mark

  # Set all of the ticks short
  tickend <- rep(shortend, length(ticks))

  # Get the position within each cycle, 0, 1, 2, ..., 8, 0, 1, 2. ...
  cycleIdx <- ticknums - 1

  # Set the 'major' ticks long
  tickend[cycleIdx == 0] <- longend

  # Where to place the longer tick marks that are between each base For base 10, this
  # will be at each 5
  longtick_after_base <- floor(ticks_per_base / 2)
  tickend[cycleIdx == longtick_after_base] <- midend

  if (delog) {
    ticksCopy <- ticks

    regScale <- log(ticks, base)

    majorTicks <- sort(
      unique(
        c(
          minpow,
          regScale[which(regScale %in% majorTicks)],
          maxpow,
          majorTicks
        )
      )
    )

    expandScale <- c()

    if (length(majorTicks) > 1) {
      for (i in 1:(length(majorTicks) - 1)) {
        expandScale <- c(
          expandScale,
          seq(majorTicks[i], majorTicks[i + 1], length.out = (ticks_per_base + 1))
        )
      }

      ticks <- unique(expandScale)

      # Set all of the ticks short
      tickend <- rep(shortend, length(ticks))

      # Set the 'major' ticks long
      tickend[which(ticks %in% majorTicks)] <- longend
    }
  }

  tickdf <- data.frame(value = ticks, start = start, end = tickend)

  tickdf
}
```

Comment: what an impressive answer! this could make my day :)
the only question that remains to me: how can I make the ticks appear outside instead of inside the plot?

Comment: well that's a good question, I tried here but couldn't find an answer

Comment: This problem was solved here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58485334/ggplot2-annotation-ticks-on-the-outside-of-the-plot-region