# date_minor_breaks in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a beginner in `ggplot2`. I am unable to use `date_minor_breaks` to show quarterly "ticks" on x-axis.

Here's my code:

```
x<-c(seq(1:12))
time<-c("2010Q1","2010Q2","2010Q3","2010Q4","2011Q1","2011Q2", "2011Q3","2011Q4","2012Q1","2012Q2","2012Q3","2012Q4")
z<-data.frame(type = x,time = time)
z$time = as.yearqtr(z$time)
z$time = as.Date(z$time)
ggplot(data = z, aes(x=time,y=type)) +
geom_point() + 
scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y",date_minor_breaks = "3 months",name = "Year") +
theme_tufte() +
theme(legend.position = "none")
```

I researched this topic on SO [Formatting dates with scale_x_date in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576095/formatting-dates-with-scale-x-date-in-ggplot2) and on https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/542, and found that there were some issues reported on this topic. However, I didn't quite follow the conversation about changes to `ggplot2` because it's been only 6 days since I started using ggplot2.

Here's the graph I got (it doesn't have any ticks)...

[image]

Here's a sample graph with "tick marks" generated from Excel. Please ignore values because my point of creating this Excel chart is to demonstrate what I am looking for--i.e. "quarterly ticks". I'd appreciate your help.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may have to make major breaks every three months and then pad your labels with blanks to give the illusion of major (labeled) and minor (unlabeled) ticks.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25279230/2461552) for another example.

First manually make the breaks for the tick marks at every quarter.

```
breaks_qtr = seq(from = min(z$time), to = max(z$time), by = "3 months")
```

Then make the year labels and pad these labels with three blanks after each number.

```
labels_year = format(seq(from = min(z$time), to = max(z$time), by = "1 year"), "%Y")
labs = c(sapply(labels_year, function(x) {
    c(x, rep("", 3))
    }))
```

Now use the breaks and the labels with the `labels` and `breaks` arguments in `scale_x_date`.  Notice that I'm not using `date_labels` and `date_breaks` for this.

```
ggplot(data = z, aes(x=time,y=type)) +
    geom_point() + 
    scale_x_date(labels = labs, breaks = breaks_qtr, name = "Year") +
    theme_tufte() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should also define your (major) date breaks:

```
ggplot(data = z, aes(x=time, y=type)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", name = "Year", date_minor_breaks="3 months",
               limits = c(as.Date(as.yearqtr("2009Q4")),
                          as.Date(as.yearqtr("2013Q2"))),
               expand=c(0,0), date_labels = "%Y") +
      theme(legend.position = "none")
```

And some other "fancy" stuff to align the minor ticks with the major ticks (I guess there a better ways to do this, but this works).

[image]

Comment: Where are the ticks? I believe what you are seeing is gridline and not the tick. Please see the Excel version in my question above--it doesn't have gridlines but does have ticks...

Comment: Than you could define date_breaks as 3 months and than manually define the labels and leave blanks