# Customize x-axis using scale_x_datetime() function in r

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, axis

[image]
I would like to show tick marks in the center of each bar, but only include labels for every other date. In the past, for continuous data, I've done something like this:

```
ylabs = seq(0, 4000, 250)
ylabs[-(seq(1, 31, 4))] = ""

scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 4000, 250), labels = ylabs, limits = c(0,  4000))
```

This method is annoying, but I cannot figure out how to solve this using ggplot2 functions. My best guess is to adopt my method above as follows:

```
labels = as.character(unique(Daily.Events$DateOnly))
labels[-seq(from = 1, to = length(labels), by = 2)] = ""
```

and some how insert the custom labels in the scale_x_datetime() function below:

```
g = ggplot(Daily.Events, aes(DateOnly, Count))
g = g + geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "black")
g = g + scale_x_datetime(name = "Date", 
                         breaks = date_breaks("1 days"),
                         labels = date_format(format = "%b %d"),
                         expand = c(0,0))

g = g + scale_y_continuous(name = "Daily Events")
g = g + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1))
plot(g)
```

Can anyone offer a better solution? I appreciate any help and criticism provided!

Comment: What about `date_breaks = "2 day"` instead of `"1 day"`?

Comment: Are you sure you have `POSIXt` values and not `Date`s? Anyway, the datetime and date scales have parameters `date_breaks` and `date_labels`. Use these instead if `breaks` and `labels`.

Comment: i played around with date_breaks and date_labels before posting. they produced the same result. i originally had date_break = "2 day", and it produced the labels i wanted, but did not place a tick mark at the unlabeled bars.

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible by adding a small example dataset?  Ideas for how to do this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  An related example [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39259445/2461552)