# ggplot2: ticks not showing at minor_breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2

This may be due to a caffeine deficiency, but I can't get `minor_breaks` to produce minor tick marks in `ggplot2`. For example,

```
# Load data
data(mtcars)

# Load library 
library(ggplot2)

# Create plot
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) 
p <- p + geom_point()
p <- p + scale_x_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(2.5, 4.5, by =1))
print(p)
```

This produces the following plot:

[image]

Note: no minor tick marks at 2.5, 3.5, and 4.5. There are no errors or warnings, either. Now, if I simply change `minor_breaks` to `breaks`, *major* tick marks appear at those positions as one would expect, which makes me think that my syntax is correct and just that the minor tick marks are invisible for some reason. Point out my error and be richly rewarded with e-high-fives.

Comment: They are there: p + theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour="blue", size=0.5)) and you will see them clearly. But these are not ticks but rather minor grid lines (minor breaks do not get tick marks), to add minor ticks check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268264/drawing-minor-ticks-not-grid-ticks-in-ggplot2-in-a-date-format-axis

Comment: Hah. Thanks! ^e-fives×10⁶^

Answer (score 1):

The image you provide was not produced by the code you post. You seem to be using a theme: perhaps you deleted the line of code applying the theme or you have set a theme by default somewhere and you've forgotten about it. Either way, some themes override the default effect of `minor_breaks`. Illustration:

Your code:

```
data(mtcars)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
geom_point() +
scale_x_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(2.5, 4.5, by =1))
```

produces this:

[image]

To see the connection between `minor_breaks` and the grid lines, change the values to something like: `scale_x_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(2.3, 4.3, by =1))`:

[image]

I believe you are using the classic theme: If you add `+theme_classic()` to the previous code, you get:

[image]

showing that the gridlines set by `minor_breaks` are overridden and disappear.