# Insert blanks into a vector for, e.g., minor tick labels in R

Tags: r, vector, plot, sequence, axis-labels

This question relates generally to a previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490071/adding-minor-tick-marks-to-the-x-axis-in-ggplot2-with-no-labels) concerning the creation of minor tick marks on a `ggplot2` axis and specifically to a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490071/adding-minor-tick-marks-to-the-x-axis-in-ggplot2-with-no-labels#comment20194683_14490652) in the answer to that question suggesting a function to insert blanks into a sequence may prove useful.

As I frequently add minor tick marks to similar plots, I took a stab at creating such a function (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34533473/2726564) below).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The following function allows the user to request that every *n*<sup>th</sup> element `nth` of a vector `x` either be (1) replaced with a empty character placeholder (`empty = TRUE`; default) or (2) omitted from the vector (`empty = FALSE`).  Additionally, it provides the option of requesting the inverse (`inverse = TRUE`; not default) of the operation.  The functionality is illustrated with some examples below.

First, the function:

```
every_nth <- function(x, nth, empty = TRUE, inverse = FALSE) 
  {
  if (!inverse) {
    if(empty) {
      x[1:nth == 1] <- ""
      x
      } else {
        x[1:nth != 1]
        }
    } else {
      if(empty) {
        x[1:nth != 1] <- ""
        x
        } else {
          x[1:nth == 1]
        }
    }
}
```

Some examples of replacing or omitting vector elements:

```
numvec <- 0:20
charvec <- LETTERS

## Replace every 3rd element with an empty character
every_nth(numvec, 3) # conversion to character vector

[1] ""   "1"  "2"  ""   "4"  "5"  ""   "7"  "8"  ""   "10" "11" ""   "13"
[15] "14" ""   "16" "17" ""   "19" "20"

every_nth(charvec, 3)
[1] ""  "B" "C" ""  "E" "F" ""  "H" "I" ""  "K" "L" ""  "N" "O" ""  "Q"
[18] "R" ""  "T" "U" ""  "W" "X" ""  "Z"

## Omit (drop) every 3rd element
every_nth(numvec, 3, empty = FALSE) # vector mode is preserved
[1]  1  2  4  5  7  8 10 11 13 14 16 17 19 20

every_nth(charvec, 3, empty = FALSE)
[1] "B" "C" "E" "F" "H" "I" "K" "L" "N" "O" "Q" "R" "T" "U" "W" "X" "Z"
```

However, for the creation of minor ticks, it is preferred to return the inverse of this operation using the `inverse = TRUE` option:

```
## Retain every 3rd element, replacing all others with an empty character
every_nth(numvec, 3, inverse = TRUE) # conversion to character vector
[1] "0"  ""   ""   "3"  ""   ""   "6"  ""   ""   "9"  ""   ""   "12" ""  
[15] ""   "15" ""   ""   "18" ""   ""

every_nth(charvec, 3, inverse = TRUE)
[1] "A" ""  ""  "D" ""  ""  "G" ""  ""  "J" ""  ""  "M" ""  ""  "P" "" 
[18] ""  "S" ""  ""  "V" ""  ""  "Y" ""

## Retain every 3rd element, omitting (dropping) all other elements
every_nth(numvec, 3, empty = FALSE, inverse = TRUE) # vector mode is preserved
[1]  0  3  6  9 12 15 18

every_nth(charvec, 3, empty = FALSE, inverse = TRUE)
[1] "A" "D" "G" "J" "M" "P" "S" "V" "Y"
```

To illustrate the function's use in the creation of minor ticks:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm(1000))

## ggplot2 default axis labelling
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
p
```

[image: default labelling]

```
## Add minor ticks to axes
custom_breaks <- seq(-3, 3, 0.25)
p + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = custom_breaks,
                     labels = every_nth(custom_breaks, 4, inverse = TRUE)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = custom_breaks,
                     labels = every_nth(custom_breaks, 2, inverse = TRUE))
```

[image: custom labelling]

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. I hope this gets incorporated into ggplot someday! Solved my problem.

Comment: Ditto! This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: when plotting with ggplot2, adding minor ticks seems to be difficult. this could be a nice workaround. however: there is no option to have the minor ticks be shorter than the major ticks, which would be nice in some cases. so: for an incorporation in ggplot2, this issue should also be adressed :)