# Custom number of ticks on y axis for a boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

Here is sample code:

```
library("ggpubr")

# Load data
data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth

# Basic plot
ggboxplot(df, x = "dose", y = "len", width = 0.8)
```

It produces plot:

[image]

I need to have more ticks on `y` axis. I need to be able to set a custom number of the ticks that will be displayed on `y` axis. For example to make display on `y` axis `5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30` ticks. How can set the number of ticks for `y` axis that I need?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335836/increase-number-of-axis-ticks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add more ticks you need to specify the values manually to the `breaks` argument of any `scale_*_continuous()` function.

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
# Load data
data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth

# Basic plot
ggboxplot(df, x = "dose", y = "len", width = 0.8) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(5, 30, 5))
```

[image]

If you only wanted the ticks to be present but wanted to control which labels were displayed, you could do something like the following with the `labels` argument by passing a parsing function.

```r
ggboxplot(df, x = "dose", y = "len", width = 0.8) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(5, 30, 5), labels = function(x){
    case_when(x%%10==0 ~ as.character(x),
              TRUE ~ "")
  })
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: you don't need that labelling hack any more - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67163923/7941188

Comment: whoa! Thanks for including this, I did not realize this!