# scale_x_continuous(minor_breaks = ...) does not draw minor grid lines properly when using ggplot2 and geom_sf to draw a map

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I want to add the minor gridlines and tickmarkers (Shorter sticks and without ticklabels) to my map plot, I used   **scale_x_continuous(minor_breaks = ....)**, but this didn't work. I've tried some of the methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490071/adding-minor-tick-marks-to-the-x-axis-in-ggplot2-with-no-labels), but that didn't work either.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Here is the code and output figure.

```
library("sf")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("tidyverse")

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
usa = filter(world,admin =="United States of America")

# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = usa, fill = "lightblue",color = "black",alpha=.9) +
  coord_sf(
    xlim = c(-119, -74),
    ylim = c(22, 51),
   default_crs = sf::st_crs(4326),
    crs = st_crs("ESRI:102003"),
    expand = TRUE,
    lims_method = "box",
    label_axes = list(
      bottom = "E", top = "E",
      left = "N", right = "N"
    )) +
  xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL) +
  ### adding grid lines on the top
  geom_hline(yintercept = seq(0, 90, by=5), 
             color = "blue", linetype = "solid", size = 0.5) +
   scale_x_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(-170, 0, by = 10),
                     breaks = seq(-170, 0, by = 20)
                       )+
  theme_bw()+
  theme( 
    # panel.grid=element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = NA),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 12 ),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey"),
    panel.grid = element_line(colour = 'blue', size = 0.5),
    axis.ticks.length=unit(.4, "cm"),
  )
```

The red parts are what I want.
[image]

Comment: Maybe you could add `geom_vline(xintercept = seq(-120, -60, by=20), color = "red", linetype = "solid", size = 0.5) +`

Answer (score 1):

A potential hack to this is to create the breaks on a sequence of 10 `seq(-170, 0, by = 10)` **but labelling only the lines you want** with a custom function:

```r
library("sf")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("tidyverse")

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
usa <- filter(world, admin == "United States of America")

# This is the custom function, does not produce labels on 120, 100, etc.
label_fun <- function(x) {
  s <- lapply(x, function(y) {
    if ((y %in% seq(-160, 0, 20))) return("")
    y <- paste0(abs(y), "ºW")
    return(y)
  })
  unlist(s)
}

# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = usa, fill = "lightblue", color = "black", alpha = .9) +
  coord_sf(
    xlim = c(-119, -74),
    ylim = c(22, 51),
    default_crs = sf::st_crs(4326),
    crs = st_crs("ESRI:102003"),
    expand = TRUE,
    lims_method = "box",
    label_axes = list(
      bottom = "E", top = "E",
      left = "N", right = "N"
    )
  ) +
  xlab(NULL) +
  ylab(NULL) +
  ### adding grid lines on the top
  geom_hline(
    yintercept = seq(0, 90, by = 5),
    color = "blue", linetype = "solid", size = 0.5
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
   # Modify breaks
    breaks = seq(-170, 0, by = 10),
    # And labels
    labels = label_fun
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    # panel.grid=element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = NA),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey"),
    panel.grid = element_line(colour = "blue", size = 0.5),
    axis.ticks.length = unit(.4, "cm"),
  )
```

[image]

Comment: @diegherman, Thanks for your answer! But I want shorter minor tickmarks. Do you have any ideas?