# ggplot2 Tick Marks on Axis Grid Lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I am working on a project to create stringlines with GTFS feeds. Given the visual complexity of these plots, I am hoping to simplify their panel grids as much as possible while still making them visually rich. As such, I was wondering whether it was possible to convert the minor gridlines in a ggplot object to tick marks on the horizontal grid lines, as is done in some professional stringline softwares (eg. https://metra.com/newsroom/how-metra-schedules-are-made).

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I don't think this can be done automatically (e.g., via `theme()`), I suspect you'll need to generate the ticks manually (i.e., `geom_segment`) and disable minor gridlines in the theme

Comment: Perhaps this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490071/adding-minor-tick-marks-to-the-x-axis-in-ggplot2-with-no-labels