# how to add minor axis and remove major axis by ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I have the following two questions:
(1) I want to get the label to be between two ticks. My original thought was to add the secondary ticks and remove the primary ticks, but axis.minor.ticks.length.y doesn't work
(2) Add stat_summary points at the legend
Thank you very much for answering your questions!

Here is the code and figure:

```
library("ggplot2")
dt <- data.frame(
  ca = rep(c("Oesophageal cancer", "Gastric cancer", "Colorectal cancer"), 3),
  var1 = c(1:3, -4:-6, 7:9),
  var2 = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 3)
)

dt %>% 
  ggplot(aes(var1, ca, fill = var2))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.8)+
  stat_summary(fun=sum, geom="point",colour="grey40", fill="grey40", shape=20, size=2)+
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, colour="grey30", linetype="dotted")+
  theme(
    axis.minor.ticks.length.y = rel(0.5)
  )
```

Objective: Change Figure 1 to Figure 2 style
[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Hmmm, yes this approach won't work with just `ggplot2` - there are no minor ticks in ggplot. But [I think the `ggh4x` package may have you covered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67163923/903061)

Comment: But for continuous variables, `axis.minor.ticks.length.x` works well. So ggplot2 isn't generally used to add minor ticks?

Comment: Discrete scales don't allow minor breaks, see https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5434. You'd have to convert to a continuous encoding of your y-axis and give the appropriate labels to make this work.

Comment: @tengy interesting, I think it's a new feature I was unaware of. I'm running ggplot2 version 3.4.0 and when I try to set it I get *"The `axis.minor.ticks.length.x` theme element is not defined in the element hierarchy."*, but I can see on the online documentation that it's part of the current 3.5.0 release.

Comment: @GregorThomas there's quite a lot of new stuff in it - mainly due to the guide system being switched to ggproto. It looks like teunbrand has written most of the new code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert to a continuous scale to use minor ticks, since there are no minor breaks on a discrete axis:

```r
dt %>% 
  ggplot(aes(var1, as.numeric(factor(ca)), fill = var2)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.8, orientation = 'y') +
  stat_summary(orientation = 'y', fun = sum, geom = "point", colour = "grey40", 
               fill = "grey40", aes(shape = 'average'), size = 2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, colour="grey30", linetype = "dotted") +
  scale_y_continuous('ca', labels = levels(factor(dt$ca)), 
                     breaks = seq_along(levels(factor(dt$ca)))) +
  scale_shape_manual(NULL, values = 20) +
  guides(y = guide_axis(minor.ticks = TRUE), 
         fill = guide_legend(order = 1),
         shape = guide_legend(order = 2)) +
  theme(axis.minor.ticks.length.y = unit(3, 'mm'),
        axis.ticks.length.y = unit(0, 'mm'),
        legend.key = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it helped me a lot! I would also like to ask how to add points to the legend, like the "Total percent change" in figure 2.

Comment: This is a bit of a deviation from my expected result. I would like the points and color blocks to be separate in the legend, like in figure 2. I had an idea before,  to add D (D = A + B + C) to var2, with fill mapped to ABC and color mapped to D, but I was unsuccessful and I couldn't achieve anything like figure 2.

Comment: @tengy I see - check my update. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes! pretty much perfect! Thanks again for your answer, it was a great help!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, ggplot2 doesn't have the functionality to add secondary ticks between axis breaks for discrete scales. But thanks to ggplot2's flexibility, we can add them manually without much hassle, just by drawing some lines (segments) just on the vertical axis, and adding a setting using `coord_cartesian` so that graphic elements out of the plot's boundaries don't get removed.

To position the ticks on the vertical axis of a discrete variable between each text label, we have to create a sequence of numbers equal to the axis breaks minus 0.5, because discrete values mapped to an axis have a numeric vertical position, so subtracting 0.5 will give us the middle position between each label.

To draw outside of the plot boundaries, we have to add hard limits for the x axis that will allow us to draw elements in the plot without stretching the vertical axis to fit them, because by default ggplot wants all plotted elements inside the plot area, and will stretch the axes to fit them. We do this in the `limits_x_axis` object.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dt <- data.frame(
  ca = rep(c("Oesophageal cancer", "Gastric cancer", "Colorectal cancer"), 3),
  var1 = c(1:3, -4:-6, 7:9),
  var2 = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 3)
)

#values for the y axis
middle_ticks_positions <- seq(0.5, length(unique(dt$ca))+0.5, by = 1)

#limits for the x axis
limits_x_axis <- c(min(dt$var1)*1.2, max(dt$var1)*1.5)

dt %>% 
  ggplot(aes(var1, ca, fill = var2))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.8)+
  annotate("segment", 
           x = -8.2, xend = -8.6, #adjust the length of ticks as you need
           y = middle_ticks_positions, yend = middle_ticks_positions) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off", xlim = limits_x_axis) +
  stat_summary(fun=sum, geom="point",colour="grey40", fill="grey40", shape=20, size=2)+
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, colour="grey30", linetype="dotted")+
  theme(
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
  )
```

[image: ggplot with ticks between text labels]